# Wildcard subdomain with dynamic subfolders, i.e. sub.example.com/folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory, wildcard-subdomain

I have wildcard subdomains set up where the subname is incorporated in the code to determine a username. So name.domain.com gives the value Name. That works fine. But I'd like to have "wildcard subfolders" where if it's a numeric value, say name.domain.com/**2**, attribute the numerically titled subfolder to the page's code as well. In that case, "**2**" would be the 'subfolder' value.

In */public_html/wildcard/index.html* I have the following,

```
<?php
$subname = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$subname = explode( ".", $subname );
$subname = array_shift( $subname );
$subname = ucwords( $subname );
if (isset($subname)) {$comma=", ";} ?>
```

That sets the subdomain to variable $subname (with first letter capitalized).
Now how could I make variable **$subfolder** indicate the subfolder if it is a numeric value? example.domain.com/56 would make $subfolder "**56**". The value is then called in the file by,

```
<?php echo $subfolder;?>
```

Any help would be tremendous. Thank you.